# How to load svg files with d3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to load a bunch of SVG image files (I only have one right now, but I will have more) to make a kind of toolbar. So I set the data of my selection with objects that have the file name. Then I call `enter()`, then I try to call `append()` with a function to load a different SVG element depending on the data, but I just get errors there. From looking at the error it seems like d3 is assuming the argument to `append` was a string, but the documentation says you can pass it a function as well. Am I doing this correctly, or is there an easier way to load SVG files?
(the actual function that loads the SVG might not work, I haven't gotten that to work yet, but that's not the immediate issue)

```
toolbarBtns.selectAll('.toolbar-btn')
      .data([
        {
          img: 'img/erase.svg',
          onclick: function() {
            clear();
            update();
          }
        }
      ])
      .enter()
      .append(function(d) {
        var btn = null;
        d3.xml(d.img, 'image/svg+xml', function(xml) {
          btn = this.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
        });
        while (!btn)
          ;
        console.log(btn);
        return btn;
      })
      .attr('class', 'toolbar-btn')
      .attr('width', '40')
      .attr('height', '40')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return 5 + i * 40;
      })
      .attr('y', '5')
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(this).select('svg circle')
                .attr('fill', 'red');
      })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this).select('svg circle')
                .attr('fill', 'none');
      })
      .on('click', function(d, i) {
        d.onclick.apply(this, [d, i]);
      });
```

Comment: Would appending an svg image object work -

  `<image x="200" y="200" width="40px" height="40px" xlink:href="myimage.png"></image>`?

Comment: @brenzy Oh, maybe, I didn't know you could do that. I'm pretty new to d3 and SVG.

Comment: @brenzy That kind of works but doesn't do exactly what I need. That creates an SVG image element, but then I can't get at any of the underlying structure of the SVG file. I wanted to be able to do that so I could, for example, change the stroke of the button to a different color when you hover over it. But I think I can find another way to do this.